# How to round Double to significant digit

Tags: java, rounding

I have a application which reads SAS xpt file and stores column value into `ByteBuffer` and then using `getValue()` method of it to get Double object. Now I have to print `Double` upto 12 significant digit after decimal. I found one answer from this from which is working fine but few cases

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(dblColumnData.doubleValue());
System.out.println(String.format("%."+15+"G", bd));
```

Here **15** is given because there are 3 digits in integer part and there must be 12 significant digit after decimal.

Cases where it is not working is because `BigDecimal` created from `Double`. If I print Double then it contains more than 12 digits after decimal and it round correctly with same above approach.

Therefore I think if I can get similar format method for `Double` the it will solve my problem.

Comment: Do you really mean *significant* digits? I.e. `123456.123456` contains 12 significant digits, but only 6 decimal places. I suspect you mean that you need 12 decimal places?

Comment: Looks like @EJP is convinced it's decimal places :-)

Comment: What other methods does dblColumnData have?  It seems likely that you should properly be converting it to BigDecimal in some other way without going through double.

Comment: @Duncan yes I mean 12 places after decimal. If i pass just 12 then format method is just returning 9 digit after decimal so I am passing 15 and returning correct values

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it somehow like this:

```
static double roundTo(double d, int digit) {
    double exp = Math.pow(10, digit);
    d *= exp;
    d = Math.round(d);
    return d / exp;
}
```

The following would round the number to 3 places after the comma and print it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(roundTo(7.34343434, 3));
}
```

Will print "7.343"

Comment: You can't round doubles to exact decimal places, and he doesn't have doubles, he has BigDecimals.

Comment: @EJP No, he has doubles. He's tried to use BigDecimals as part of a solution.

Comment: This solution is just working fine. He used BigDecimals in order to do the formatting.